# Passing the hash of an url to a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using a jQuery plugin that uses a hash-url - `#/page/1...5`

I'm trying to get the page number and use it with PHP without reloading the page.

I tried to send it with AJAX from a javascript variable to a PHP (post) variable but it is redirecting me to another page.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'other_page.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: ({id: 1}),
    success: function(data){
        //
    }
});
```

I'm trying to use the id-data (example above) in the same page where the ajax-script is. I hope someone can help me achieve this.

Comment: On what event are you sending this data?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the hash with

```
window.location.hash
```

You must then tokenize it to get the number

```
var page = window.location.hash.split('/')[2]
```

You could then forward it on with ajax with

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'other_page.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: ({id: page}),
    success: function(data){
       //
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I want to forward it to the same page (with the ajax script), not to another page. Is this possible?

Comment: Say your link was <a href="#/page/2/">2</a> clicking that would then update the hash.  If you observe the hash change `$(window).on('hashchange', function() {});` and put the ajax code above, in that function, it would make a request to the server everytime someone clicks to change the page. You can then populate the appropriate dom element with the result.